# Javascript Pagination Issue

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to make a simple Javascript pagination function, but I'm having this issue where instead of iterating through the array, it keeps adding new list items to the innerhtml.

- I have tried creating an element and appending it to the DOM.
- I have tried using if/else statements to display the list items I
  want.

```
<body>
    <div class='result'></div>
    <button class="add">+</button>
   <script src='pretty.js'></script>
</body>
```

```
let dogs =  [
    'goldendoodle',
    'poodle',
    'afghan hound',
    'golden retriever',
    'labrador',
    'chihuahua',
    'pitbull',
    'german shepherd',
    'greyhound',
    'bull terrier'
  ]
  let high = 1;
  let low = 0;
  let result = document.querySelector('.result');
  let add = document.querySelector('.add');
  function Pagination(low,high) {


    for(var i = 0 ; i < dogs.length;i++) {
        let answer = document.createElement('div');
        answer.classList.add('dogs-dom');

        answer.innerHTML = dogs[i];
        result.appendChild(answer);

        if(i >= low && i < high) {

                answer.style.display ='block';


        } 
        if(i < low || i > high) {

            answer.style.display ='none';
        }




    }

  }
  Pagination(low,high);
  add.addEventListener('click', () => {

      low += 2;
      high += 2;

    Pagination(low,high);
  });
```

When I click the button, I want the next two array items to appear and replace the last two shown.

Answer (score 1):

To use the approach you've outlined above you'll need to clear the `innerHtml` of the `result` element before appending new children. At the top of your `Pagination` function try `result.innerHtml = '';`.

That said if you are using a hide/show approach to paginate the list it would be more efficient to create the dom elements only once and modify the `style.display` property of each instead of clearing out the `result` and re-creating all of the `answer` `div`s on every click.

Comment: thank you so much :) . I feel so stupid lol, clearing the result.innerHTML was exactly what I needed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Pagination` function only adds elements to the dom each time it is called.

You can either remove the existing elements every time `Pagination` is called, and render only those that should be displayed, e.g.:

```
function Pagination(low,high) {
  result.innerHTML = ''; // remove all children of result

  // only render the children which should be visible
  for(var i = low ; i < high;i++) {
    let answer = document.createElement('div');
    answer.classList.add('dogs-dom');
    answer.innerHTML = dogs[i];
    result.appendChild(answer);
  }
}
```

Or you can use `display: block;` / `display: none`. (Will not scale very well with large lists)

```
function Pagination(low,high) {
  // only append all dogs once
  if(result.childElementCount === 0) {
    for(var i = 0; i < dogs.length;i++) {
      let answer = document.createElement('div');
      answer.classList.add('dogs-dom');
      answer.style.display ='none';
      answer.innerHTML = dogs[i];
      result.appendChild(answer);
    }
  }

  // toggle display: none / block for each element
  for(var i = 0; i < dogs.length;i++) {
    if(i >= low && i < high)
      answer.style.display ='block';
    else
      answer.style.display ='none';
  }
}
```

As a bonus, heres a reusable pagination class example:

```js
function Pagination(container, items) {
  this.container = container;
  this.result = container.querySelector('.result');
  this.prevBtn = container.querySelector('.prev');
  this.nextBtn = container.querySelector('.next');
  this.items = items;
  this.offset = 0;
  this.limit = 5;
  this.updateDom();
  this.prevBtn.onclick = this.prevPage.bind(this);
  this.nextBtn.onclick = this.nextPage.bind(this);
}

Pagination.prototype.nextPage = function() {
  if((this.offset + this.limit) < this.items.length)
    this.offset += this.limit;
  this.updateDom();
};

Pagination.prototype.prevPage = function() {
  if(this.offset >= this.limit)
    this.offset -= this.limit;
  this.updateDom();  
};

Pagination.prototype.updateDom = function() {
  this.result.innerHTML = '';
  let stop = Math.min(this.offset + this.limit, this.items.length);
  for(let i = this.offset; i < stop; i++) {
    let el = document.createElement("div");
    el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.items[i]));
    this.result.appendChild(el);
  }
  
  let hasPrev = this.offset > 0;
  if(hasPrev)
    this.prevBtn.classList.remove('hide');
  else
    this.prevBtn.classList.add('hide');
  let hasNext = (this.offset + this.limit) < this.items.length;
  if(hasNext)
    this.nextBtn.classList.remove('hide');
  else
    this.nextBtn.classList.add('hide');
  
};

let items = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
  items.push(`Item ${i}`);
let pagination = new Pagination(document.querySelector(".paginate"), items);

// You can also programatically switch to the next / prev page:
// pagination.nextPage();
// pagination.prevPage();
```

```css
.hide { visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<div class="paginate">
  <div class="result"></div>
  <button class="prev">PREV</button>
  <button class="next">NEXT</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I dont quite understand why larger lists wont scale as well with the display method?

Comment: Changing what is visible in the document is a bit expensive. (And some methods of doing this are more expensive than others -- e.g., I've been led to believe setting `innerHTML` is particularly slow). That's fine if you're only updating a few elements occasionally, but if you start updating like hundreds of things at a time, I guess the browser might hang for a while.

Comment: @MysteriousShadow Additionally to what Cat said, even just creating / having a lot of html elements in your dom will slow down your browser quite easily. [code pen with 1m elements](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VoPadp) **BEWARE might fry your browser**

Comment: Ah that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is along the lines of what you want to do?

It tracks only a `globalIndex` (which would be like like your 'low' variable).

The `showNextTwoItems` function:
 - Notes the indexes where we should start and end
 - Clears the container div
 - Enters a while loop that appends items and increments the current index
 - Updates the globalIndex when enough items have been added

```js
let dogs = [ 'goldendoodle', 'poodle', 'afghan hound', 'golden retriever', 'labrador', 'chihuahua', 'pitbull', 'german shepherd', 'greyhound', 'bull terrier' ],  
    containerDiv = document.querySelector('.result'),
    addBtn = document.querySelector('.add'),
    globalIndex = 0; // Tracks where we left off (starts at zero)
const NUMBER_TO_SHOW = 2;
addBtn.addEventListener("click", showNextTwoItems); // Calls function on click

function showNextTwoItems(){
  let numberToShow = NUMBER_TO_SHOW, // In case we ever want to change numberToShow
      currentIndex = globalIndex, // Gets local copy of globalIndex (always < dogs.length)
      // Lets us stop looping when we've shown enough or reach the end of the array
      stopBeforeIndex = Math.min(currentIndex + numberToShow, dogs.length);
  containerDiv.innerHTML = ""; // Clears div
  while(currentIndex < stopBeforeIndex){
    // Creates and appends a text node with the next dog
    const newItem = document.createTextNode(dogs[currentIndex]);
    containerDiv.appendChild(newItem);
    // Creates and appends a line break 
    const lineBreak = document.createElement("BR");
    containerDiv.appendChild(lineBreak);
    // Moves on to the next index
    currentIndex++;
  }
  // Updates global index (making sure it is not too big for the array)
  globalIndex = currentIndex < dogs.length ? currentIndex : 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="add">+</button>
<div class='result'></div>
```